# Programmatically downloading all files from a folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, download, php

I need to create a script to download all files from a certain folder on my Sharepoint, or alternatively download using a wildcard (there will only be one file in this folder but its filename changes.

I am able to do this when giving the exact filename e.g.

`https://ontariogov.sharepoint.com/:u:/r/sites/My%20Site/Status%20Reports/Status-List1187648Z.xml?download=1` but don't know how to adapt this for a wildcard or to download all from the folder